# How to use Sideline in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

How can I convey to my manager that I feel upset when I am not chosen for some critical activities?
Is the following sentence correct?

> I feel that I am sideline for major/critical activities.

Comment: *Sideline* as a verb is transitive. I have edited your question to make you the person who is sidelined.

Comment: What did you find when you looked up [sideline](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sideline) in a dictionary?

Comment: @anton you shouldn't edit questions to answer them...

Comment: @JeffUK yes I realise that is sometimes a problem. In this case I suspected a mere typo, and resisted the temptation to make my comment the answer, for that indeed would be manipulative. I believe the question remains unanswered.

Comment: You are on the sideline or you are sidelined.  And likely someone sidelined you.